# Use all word functionalities in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want to create my jsp page which contains word like functionality where user can add text, save them, do track change function. change fonts and color. Is there any plugin or java script plugin available to implement this kind of functionality in project.?

Comment: please specify your problem better. and do a google research in the topic

Comment: i want to implement functionality like microsoft word in my jsp page.Client wants to use my application same way they use microsoft word. they can add text and everything and at the end one word file will generate. i google but there are paid versions avail. on net.i want to use some open source.

Comment: use tinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use CKEditor for the same.
CKEditor will give you all the functionality like word file.

CKEditor.com

Answer (score 1):

use tinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/)

to display word-like editor.

sample:  http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) which is a javascript plugin that does text wysiwyg editing